# MySQL: Disparador para actualizar el orden de una lista tras borrar un elemento de ésta

Tags: mysql, mysql-workbench, trigger

Tengo una tabla de paso tal que así:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS incluidas(
    id_lista_youtube SMALLINT UNSIGNED NOT NULL, 
    id_cancion SMALLINT UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
    orden TINYINT UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
    fecha_inclusion DATETIME DEFAULT now(), 
    PRIMARY KEY(id_lista_youtube, id_cancion),
    CONSTRAINT fk_incluidas_1 FOREIGN KEY (id_lista_youtube) REFERENCES listas_youtube(id_lista_youtube),
    CONSTRAINT fk_incluidas_2 FOREIGN KEY (id_cancion) REFERENCES canciones(id_cancion)
    )
```

Y he creado un disparador para que, cada vez que un usuario de mi página web borre una canción (o la referencia a una canción, su `id_cancion`) de una de sus listas personales, todas las canciones posteriores a ella pertenecientes a esa lista en concreto actualicen su `orden`; por ejemplo, si se borra la 4, que la 5 pase a ser la 4, la 6 la 5, etc.:

```
DELIMITER $$
    
    CREATE TRIGGER borrado_cancion

    AFTER DELETE ON incluidas FOR EACH ROW
    
    BEGIN

        SET @orden = (SELECT orden FROM incluidas WHERE id_cancion = OLD.id_cancion);
        SET @id_lista = (SELECT id_lista_youtube FROM incluidas WHERE id_cancion = OLD.id_cancion);
        
        UPDATE incluidas SET orden = OLD.orden - 1 WHERE OLD.orden > @orden AND id_lista_youtube = @id_lista;
        
    END;

$$ DELIMITER ;
```

Antes siquiera de analizar el código, el principal problema es que no consigo implementarlo; lo intento ejecutar en Workbench y no pasa nada.

Si elimino el espacio entre `$$ DELIMITER` y `;`, entonces primero hace el `CREATE TRIGGER` y a continuación me dice que no ha podido crear el disparador porque hay un error de sintaxis:

```
22:09:00    CREATE TRIGGER borrado_cancion   AFTER DELETE ON incluidas FOR EACH ROW       BEGIN          SET @orden = (SELECT orden FROM incluidas WHERE id_cancion = OLD.id_cancion);         SET @id_lista = (SELECT id_lista_youtube FROM incluidas WHERE id_cancion = OLD.id_cancion);            UPDATE incluidas SET orden = OLD.orden - 1 WHERE OLD.orden > @orden AND id_lista_youtube = @id_lista;           END;  $$ DELIMITER;   0 row(s) affected   0.000 sec

22:09:00    CREATE TRIGGER borrado_cancion   AFTER DELETE ON incluidas FOR EACH ROW       BEGIN          SET @orden = (SELECT orden FROM incluidas WHERE id_cancion = OLD.id_cancion);         SET @id_lista = (SELECT id_lista_youtube FROM incluidas WHERE id_cancion = OLD.id_cancion);            UPDATE incluidas SET orden = OLD.orden - 1 WHERE OLD.orden > @orden AND id_lista_youtube = @id_lista;           END;  $$ DELIMITER;   Error Code: 1064 You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '$$ DELIMITER' at line 1
```

Pero sí lo crea, o al menos aparece en el navegador:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

El asunto es que una vez "implementado" (sigo sin estar seguro de si lo ha hecho o no, la verdad), el borrado de canciones desde mi web deja de funcionar, como si el disparador interfiriese con el script jQuery + PHP que controla el proceso -y que vuelve a funcionar perfectamente una vez eliminas el disparador-.

¿Se os ocurre qué puede ser?

Comment: No le veo mucho sentido a lo que quieres hacer. En caso de tener realmente necesidad de esto, yo crearía un orden dinámico, basado en el valor de la misma columna que estás intentando mover. ¿Por qué? Porque es menos costoso y menos peligroso eso que estar actualizando filas constantemente. Si se borró la fila del orden `5` poco importa que de la `4` pase a la `6`, en cualquier contexto será bastante simple mostrar las filas con un número de orden si fuera preciso, creado de forma dinámica.

Comment: Tengo previsto que el usuario pueda cambiar la posición de las canciones dentro de la lista, por eso creé el atributo `orden`.

Comment: Eso que comentas es otra cosa. En la pregunta estás hablando de un TRIGGER que se dispararía cuando una canción sea borrada. Si cada usuario puede establecer su propio orden, es evidente que tendrías que trasladar la lógica del orden a otra tabla donde guardes el orden de las canciones por cada usuario.

Comment: Ya, ahora lo que estoy implementando es el borrado de canciones. Cuando termine me pondré a implementar la posibilidad de que el usuario altere el orden. Pero por eso he creado el atributo `orden`; de lo contrario haría un `ORDER BY fecha_inclusion`, por ejemplo.

Comment: Realmente en la tabla `cancion` el único orden que tendría sentido sería uno basado en `fecha_inclusion`, otro orden que tendría sentido sería el alfabético, otro sería por fecha de aparición... todos esos datos poderían ir en la misma tabla `cancion`. Pero, podría haber otros tipos de orden: por artista, por género, por preferencia ... etc que no tendrían sentido en tabla `cancion` porque dependen de otros datos en otra tablas o de otros contextos. Lo que ocurre aquí, creo yo, **es un error de concepto** al querer reflejar en la tabla algo que debería ir fuera de ella.

Comment: El orden es el que decida el usuario, y pretendo almacenarlo en `incluidas`, no en `canciones`; esa tabla almacena información sobre las diferentes canciones que se pueden escuchar en mi web: título, número de votos que ha recibido, vídeo de YouTube, etc.

Comment: Es lo que ya ha he dicho. Si el orden lo decide el usuario, necesitas una tabla donde, por cada usuario, tengas un orden (algo así como los favoritos). Si hay varios usuarios, supongo que cada uno querrá tener uno u otro orden. Eso no puede, ni debe, reflejarse en la tabla de canciones.

Comment: Y esa tabla es `incluidas`, que relaciona cada lista con las canciones que contiene, cada una con su orden dentro de esa lista. Luego `listas_youtube` relaciona cada lista con su dueño.

Comment: Lo que quieres hacer podría lograrse lanzando un TRIGGER que haga algo así: `UPDATE laTabla 
SET orden = orden - 1 
WHERE orden > OLD.orden` Esa consulta restaría `1` a todos los órdenes a partir del que se borró. Pero insisto en que hacer esto sería someter la tabla a cambios constantes en muchas de sus filas, lo cual no es muy recomendable.

Comment: Sí, es similar a lo que he hecho, pero por alguna razón no funciona, como he explicado en mi mensaje inicial.

Comment: Otra cosa es que MySQL **no permite modificar mediante TRIGGER la misma tabla que dispara el TRIGGER**. O sea, no puedes disparar un TRIGGER cuando algo pase en `incluidas` y modificar al mismo tiempo: mediante UPDATE, DELETE o INSERT a la misma tabla `incluidas`

Comment: Pues a hacer una tabla que almacene el orden de una canción y a otra que almacene el de las restantes sí que no le veo mucho sentido, la verdad.

Comment: Finalmente lo he solventado con PHP.

Answer (score 1):

No le veo mucho sentido a lo que quieres hacer. En caso de tener realmente necesidad de esto, yo crearía un **orden dinámico**, basado en el valor de la misma columna que estás intentando mover. ¿Por qué? Porque eso es **menos costoso** y **menos peligroso** que estar actualizando filas constantemente, programando TRIGGERS, etc.

Si se borró la fila del orden 5 poco importa que de la 4 pase a la 6, en cualquier contexto será bastante simple mostrar las filas con un número de orden si fuera preciso, creado de forma dinámica.

Veamos un ejemplo:

```
SET @counter = 0; 

SELECT 
    nombre,
    orden, 
    (@counter := @counter +1) AS new_order 
FROM incluidas 
ORDER BY orden;
```

Tendrías más o menos esto:

```
nombre           orden            new_order
-----------------------------------------------
Canción 1          1                  1
Canción 2          2                  2
Canción 3          3                  3
Canción 4          4                  4
Canción 6          6                  5
```

En este contexto el orden que interesa se estableció con un contador sobre las filas, en la columna `new_order`.  Esto es mucho más simple que estar constantemente manipulando los datos en la tabla.

Incluso, puedes programar un evento para restablecer el orden usando algo parecido a esta consulta, si estás demasiado obsesionado con el orden.

Desde MySQL 8 puedes usar [`ROW_NUMBER`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/window-function-descriptions.html#function_row-number) si quieres una fila numerada, sería algo como:

```
ROW_NUMBER OVER (PARTITION BY columnaID ORDER BY orden DESC) as new_order
```

Así evitas mantener una variable definida y autoincrementada en la consulta y, al poder poner un orden propio, puedes obtener las filas en otro orden por otras columnas sin ningún problema y sin tener que usar sub-consultas.